# How to create XML schema with namespace prefix

Tags: xml, schema

how to create xml schema for below xml i am facing problem to create schema with namespace prefix :

`<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <sch:GET_ACCT xmlns:sch="http://www.schamst.com/webservice/schemas">
            <sch:STATUS>true</sch:STATUS>
            <sch:ERRORs/>
        </sch:GET_ACCT>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move xmlns:sch="" into the SOAP-ENV:Envelope tag

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sch="http://www.schamst.com/webservice/schemas">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <sch:GET_ACCT>
            <sch:STATUS>true</sch:STATUS>
            <sch:ERRORs/>
        </sch:GET_ACCT>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Actually, I want to create XML Schema for that XML

Comment: So you need to create something like <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
<!-- your definition of xml-schema-->
</xs:schema> and put it to http://www.schamst.com/webservice/schemas

Comment: No thats not working, I need to create for below XML:<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <sch:GET_ACCT xmlns:sch="http://www.schamst.com/webservice/schemas">
         <sch:STATUS>true</sch:STATUS>
         <sch:ERRORs/>
</sch:GET_ACCT>
</S:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>